# What characters does RFC 5280 allow in the DN?

Tags: pki, rfc

I've been having a bit of trouble parsing a couple of corner cases of RFC 5280 (My ASN.1 isn't quite up to spec).

Firstly, is a lone comma allowed as part of a RDN field? Commas are common, i.e.

`CN=Wingdings, Inc`

but is a name like

`CN=,` valid?

Secondly, does the RFC allow empty field names, such as `CN=`?

Comment: Have you considered ... reading the RFC?

Comment: Well, as I said, my ASN.1 isn't that hot. And yes.

Comment: And what does the RFC tell you about this?

Comment: Uh, seriously. 

From what I see (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280) nothing, because these are corner cases that the RFC doesn't cover these corner cases specifically. If you know the section they're covered in, then feel free to point them out.

Comment: Yea ... seriously!  See my Answer

Comment: Boy, sorry about sounding snide...I kind of sound like an asshole. Was tearing my hair out trying to makes heads or tails of the RFC. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC says this (Section 4.1.2.4.)

```
   Name ::= CHOICE { -- only one possibility for now --
     rdnSequence  RDNSequence }

   RDNSequence ::= SEQUENCE OF RelativeDistinguishedName

   RelativeDistinguishedName ::=
     SET SIZE (1..MAX) OF AttributeTypeAndValue

   AttributeTypeAndValue ::= SEQUENCE {
     type     AttributeType,
     value    AttributeValue }

   AttributeType ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER

   AttributeValue ::= ANY -- DEFINED BY AttributeType
```

And then later (Appendix A)

```
-- Naming attributes of type X520CommonName

id-at-commonName        AttributeType ::= { id-at 3 }

-- Naming attributes of type X520CommonName:
--   X520CommonName ::= DirectoryName (SIZE (1..ub-common-name))
--
-- Expanded to avoid parameterized type:
X520CommonName ::= CHOICE {
      teletexString     TeletexString   (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)),
      printableString   PrintableString (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)),
      universalString   UniversalString (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)),
      utf8String        UTF8String      (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)),
      bmpString         BMPString       (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)) }
```

From this I deduce:

1. A CN value must have at least one character.
2. Just about any character is valid in a CN.

Therefore, "CN=" is not allowed, but "CN=," is allowed.

(Whether you would want to consider "," as an *acceptable* common name is a different issue, but at least it is not forbidden by the syntax rules.)

<sup>Caveat: the above is based on a cursory reading of the RFC and a bit of side-research as a sanity check.  I'm not an X.500/520 or ASN.1 expert.</sup>